# PHP Regex cut off space with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some string like this

```
Name xxx Product 1 Pc 100
Name Pci Product2Pc.200
Name Pcx Product 3 Pcs300
```

I want to turn `PC` to `Price`
**And this is result that I want**

```
Name xxx Product 1 Price 100
Name Pci Product 2 Price 200
Name Pcx Product 3 Price 300
```

At first I use

```
$pattern = array('/(\s*)Product(\s*)/', '/(\s*)(Pc\.?|Pcs)(\s*)/');
```

But it came to change all of my PC to Price

```
Name xxx Product 1 Price 100
Name Price i Product 2 Price 200
Name Price x Product 3 Price 300
```

This is my code now.

```
$pattern = array('/(\s*)Product(\s*)/', '/[^a-z](Pc\.?|Pcs)[^a-z]/');
$replacement = array(' Product ', ' Price ');
$title = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $title, -1);
```

But it result like this

```
Name xxx Product 1 Price 100
Name Pci Product Price 00
Name Pcx Product 3 Price 00
```

Thanks you.

Comment: You should change the *title* because I cannot see a `space` to change.

Comment: I don't know what the name of title to use help pls. I will change it. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
(Product)\s*(\d+)\s*Pc[.s]?\s*(\d+)
```

Replacement string:

```
$1 $2 Price $3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bI8fH0/1)

```
$string = <<<EOT
Name xxx Product 1 Pc 100
Name Pci Product2Pc.200
Name Pcx Product 3 Pcs300
EOT;
$pattern = "~(Product)\s*(\d+)\s*Pc[.s]?\s*(\d+)~";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "$1 $2 Price $3", $string);
```

Output:

```
Name xxx Product 1 Price 100
Name Pci Product 2 Price 200
Name Pcx Product 3 Price 300
```

Comment: You were quicker than me :) Anyway, please add the last semicolon at the end of the last line.

Comment: Thanks you for you help. I have some question about `Pcs` `Pric` how can I use `|` if the price have a lot of short word I try `(Pc[.s]|Pric)` It doesn't work if I use `[.s|Pric]` it only check one word but I want to check the whole word.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/lK4tP9/1 - I try to use `|` to check between `Pc or Pric` and turn it to `Price`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your attempt is not working is because you are removing things that you don't want to.

You could use the following regular expression.

```
$title = <<<DATA
Name xxx Product 1 Pc 100
Name Pci Product2Pc.200
Name Pcx Product 3 Pcs300
DATA;

$title = preg_replace('/Product\K\s*(\d+)\D+(\d+)/', ' $1 Price $2', $title);
echo $title;
```

Output:

```
Name xxx Product 1 Price 100
Name Pci Product 2 Price 200
Name Pcx Product 3 Price 300
```